# Merging array values into single key and multiple values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want the array to merge into a key value pair. look at the example below

Here is my code and array $aExtraFilter

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'CookTech' (length=8)
      'value' => string 'Broil' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'CookTech' (length=8)
      'value' => string 'Pan Fry' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'CookSkills' (length=10)
      'value' => string 'Intro' (length=5)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'CookSkills' (length=10)
      'value' => string 'Knife Skills' (length=12)
```

Here is my code:

```
    $aExtraFilter2 = [];
    $extrafilterkey = '';
    $extrafiltervalue = [];
    foreach ($aExtraFilter as $key => $value) {
        $extrafilterkey = $value['key'];
        $aExtraFilter2[$extrafilterkey] = [];
        array_push($extrafiltervalue, $value['value']);
        $aExtraFilter2[$extrafilterkey] = implode(',', $extrafiltervalue);
    }
    var_dump($aExtraFilter2);
```

the output is :

```
array (size=2)
  'CookTech' => string 'Broil,Pan Fry' (length=13)
  'CookSkills' => string 'Broil,Pan Fry,Intro,Knife Skills' (length=32)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
array (size=2)
  'CookTech' => string 'Broil,Pan Fry' (length=13)
  'CookSkills' => string 'Intro,Knife Skills' (length=32)
```

I think I'm almost there but I guess I need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does nothing because it is superseded just a bit later as the same variable is being set:

```
$aExtraFilter2[$extrafilterkey] = [];
```

This line appends to the array regardless of what you have as `$value['key']`, which is why you get all keys lumped together in the output:

```
array_push($extrafiltervalue, $value['value']);
```

This will produce a desired output:

```
// fill array of arrays
$aExtraFilter2 = [];
foreach ($aExtraFilter as $key => $value) {
    if (!array_key_exists($value['key'], $aExtraFilter2)) $aExtraFilter2[$value['key']] = [];
    $aExtraFilter2[$value['key']][] = $value['value'];
}
// convert to string (if needed at all, depends on what you're doing later)
foreach ($aExtraFilter2 as $key => $set) {
    $aExtraFilter2[$key] = join(',', $set);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to code this is by creating a temporary structure, based on the key and comprising an array with the values:

```
$tmp = [];
foreach ($aExtraFilter as $pair) {
    $tmp[$pair['key']][] = $pair['value'];
}
```

The structure would look like this afterwards:

```
[
    'CookTech' => ['Broil', 'Pan Fry'],
    'CookSkills' => ['Intro', 'Knife Skills'],
]
```

Then, you map that array against the representation you want to have:

```
$aExtraFilter2 = array_map(function($values) {
    return join(',', $values);
}, $tmp);
```

See also: [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map)